Reporting on the Process Template from Azure DevOps
I would like to pull Projects into a Power BI report based on the Process template assigned.  Does anyone know if there is an attribute that will help to do something like that?
We looked at fields, but nothing looked like it was the Process template, searching online only seemed to tell me how to customize it.  I just want to pull Projects into a report based on their process template so I'm not 'hard coding' the project names in Power BI.

Based on your description, you need to pull Projects into a Power BI report based on the Process template.
I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly pull the Projects into a Power BI report.
Currently, the fields in Analytics views only support setting the fields of Boards work items.
To meet your requirement, you can use the Script to run Rest API to export the related project info to excel file. Then you can import the excel data to Power BI to generate report.
Here are the steps:
Step1: use the following Rest APIs to get the projects and the related process template name:
Projects - List
Projects - Get Project Properties
Processes - Get
PowerShell script sample:
$token = "PAT"

$organizationname= "OrganizationName"

$GetProject="https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationname)/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$ProjectResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetProject -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

foreach($project in $ProjectResponse.value)
{
   $projectid = $project.id
   $projectname = $project.name

   $Projectprocessurl= "https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationname)/_apis/projects/$($projectid)/properties?keys=System.ProcessTemplateType&api-version=5.0-preview.1"
   $ProjectproResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Projectprocessurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

   $Processid = $ProjectproResponse.value[0].value
  

   $processnameurl="https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationname)/_apis/process/processes/$($processid)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
   $ProcessNameresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $processnameurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

   $Processname = $ProcessNameresponse.name
   echo $projectname
   echo $Processname
 
    $Output = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        projectname = $projectname
        projectid =$projectid
        Processname = $Processname
       } | Select-Object projectname, projectid,Processname
    $Output | Export-Csv C:\project1.csv -Append
}

The script will generate an excel file contains projects and related process template info.
Step3: Open PowerBI -> Home -> Get Data -> Text/CSV to import the excel file to PowerBI to generate report.

Result:


Thank you for your ideas, we don't use analytics to write the Power BI reports, we use OData flows.  It did spark and idea for our developer, but that resulted in a potential security risk that was blocked, so we are still unable to do that report as we would like at this time.  Essentially, we want to pull in the Projects that are part of a specific Process Template only, and because we can't seem to find Project attributes, we end up hard coding the Project name, and it would be nice not to have to do that.

@Stacy I am afraid that the  Odata flow doesn't contains the Process Template  attributes. I can fully understand your requirement, you can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.
